# How to align controls in one line using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align few controls in one line using bootstrap class = "form-inline", but it seems it not working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Currently I am getting the result in two lines.I want them to be displayed in one line

The code which I am using is as below

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>
    <label class="control-label">
        Please enter TB Id or TBR Id</label>
    <div class="form-search">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input id="inputValue" type="text" class="span2 search-query" />
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                    <li><a id="POA" tabindex="-1" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a id="MOD" tabindex="-1" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a id="LC" tabindex="-1" href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an url to a demo site?

Comment: add any class like span1, span2, span3, etc.

Comment: Just now I don't have any such :)

Comment: @Chanduvkm where to add these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code, hope it helps:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>
    <label class="control-label">
        Please enter TB Id or TBR Id</label>
    <span class="form-search">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input id="inputValue" type="text" class="span2 search-query" />
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                    <li><a id="POA" tabindex="-1" href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a id="MOD" tabindex="-1" href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a id="LC" tabindex="-1" href="#">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```